# Filter rows based on dynamic pattern

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have speech data in in a dataframe `df`in column `Orthographic`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Orthographic = c("this is it at least probably",
                   "well not probably it's not intuitive",
                   "sure no it's I mean it's very intuitive",
                   "I don't mean to be rude but it's anything but you know",
                   "well okay maybe"),
  Repeat = c(NA, "probably", "it's,intuitive", "I,mean,it's", NA),
  Repeat_pattern = c(NA, "\\b(probably)\\b", "\\b(it's|intuitive)\\b", "\\b(I,mean|it's)\\b", 
                     NA))
```

I want to `filter` rows based on a **dynamic pattern**, namely the occurrence of `no`, `never`, `not` as words OR `n't` **before** any of the words listed in column `Repeat`. However, using the pattern `\\b(no|never|not)\\b|n't\\b\\s` **together with** the alternation patterns in column `Repeat_pattern`, I get this error:

```
df %>%
   filter(grepl(paste0("\\b(no|never|not)\\b|n't\\b\\s", Repeat_pattern), Orthographic))
                             Orthographic         Repeat         Repeat_pattern
1    well not probably it's not intuitive       probably       \\b(probably)\\b
2 sure no it's I mean it's very intuitive it's,intuitive \\b(it's|intuitive)\\b
Warning message:
In grepl(paste0("\\b(no|never|not)\\b|n't\\b\\s", Repeat_pattern),  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I don't know why "only the first element will be used" as the two pattern components seem to connect well:

```
paste0("\\b(no|never|not)\\b|n't\\b\\s", df$Repeat_pattern)
[1] "\\b(no|never|not)\\b|n't\\b\\sNA"                     "\\b(no|never|not)\\b|n't\\b\\s\\b(probably)\\b"      
[3] "\\b(no|never|not)\\b|n't\\b\\s\\b(it's|intuitive)\\b" "\\b(no|never|not)\\b|n't\\b\\s\\b(I,mean|it's)\\b"   
[5] "\\b(no|never|not)\\b|n't\\b\\sNA"
```

The **expected output** is this:

```
2                   well not probably it's not intuitive       probably       \\b(probably)\\b
3                sure no it's I mean it's very intuitive it's,intuitive \\b(it's|intuitive)\\b
4 I don't mean to be rude but it's anything but you know    I,mean,it's    \\b(I,mean|it's)\\b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a vectorization issue here, you need to use `stringr::str_detect` here rather than `grepl`.

Also, you did not group the negative word alternatives well, all of them must reside in a single group and your `n't` is now obligatory in a string.

Alse, `NA` values are coerced to text and added to the regex patterns, while it seems you want to discard the items where `Repeat_pattern` is `NA`.

You can fix your code by using

```r
df %>%
    filter(ifelse(is.na(Repeat_pattern), FALSE, str_detect(Orthographic, paste0("(?:\\bno|\\bnever|\\bnot|n't)\\b.*", Repeat_pattern))))
```

Output:

```r
                                            Orthographic         Repeat         Repeat_pattern
1                   well not probably it's not intuitive       probably       \\b(probably)\\b
2                sure no it's I mean it's very intuitive it's,intuitive \\b(it's|intuitive)\\b
3 I don't mean to be rude but it's anything but you know    I,mean,it's    \\b(I|mean|it's)\\b
```

I also think the last pattern must be `\\b(I|mean|it's)\\b`, not `\\b(I,mean|it's)\\b`.

If there can only be whitespace between the "no" words and the word from `Repeat` column, replace `.*` with `\\s+` in my pattern. I used `.*\b` to make sure there is a match anywhere to the right of the "no" words.